# ERROR AzureNativeFileSystemStore: DirectoryIsNotEmpty

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to execute this code in Azure HdInsigth. I have a cluster Spark that is connected with Data Lake Storage.

```
spark.conf.set(
"fs.azure.sas.data.spmdevsharedstorage.blob.core.windows.net",
"xxxxxxxxxxx key xxxxxxxxxxx"
)


val shared_data = "wasbs://data@spmdevsharedstorage.blob.core.windows.net/"

//Read Csv
val dfCsv = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", true).csv(shared_data + "/test/4G-pixel.csv")
val dfCsv_final_withcolumn = dfCsv.select($"latitude",$"longitude")
val dfCsv_final = dfCsv_final_withcolumn.withColumn("new_latitude",col("latitude")*100)

//write
dfCsv_final.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").save(shared_data + "/test/4G-pixel_edit.csv")
```

The code reads the csv file well. So, when write the new file csv I see the following error:

```
20/04/03 14:58:12 ERROR AzureNativeFileSystemStore: Encountered Storage Exception for delete on Blob: https://spmdevsharedstorage.blob.core.windows.net/data/test/4G-pixel_edit.csv/_temporary/0, Exception Details: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory. Error Code: DirectoryIsNotEmpty
org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.delete(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2627)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.delete(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2637)
```

The new file csv is written to the Data Lake but the code stops. I need you to not see this error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Try removing the write mode as overwrite  and check the job

Comment: I need there to be overwrite

Comment: Then check whether the job has access to overwrite

Comment: even if I eliminate overwrite, the error still comes out

Comment: can nobody help me?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue.

I resolved it by using the below configuration.. set this to true.

```
--conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup.skipped=true
```

or

```
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup.skipped","true")
```